# How to make google links (or any other links) to open our app?

Tags: ios

I am developing a mapping application and I want that whenever a user clicks a google map's link or any other links (except a link from my own domain), it should show an option to open in my app as well.

How this can be achieved using **Associated Domains**?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm -hopefully- not mistaking, what are you looking is **[Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html)**:

> When you support universal links, iOS users can tap a link to your
>   website and get seamlessly redirected to your installed app without
>   going through Safari.

*Remark*: for supporting universal links, you have to have a paid Apple developer account.

Turning on the **Associated Domains** capability is one of the required steps to support the universal links into your application.

For more information, there is a good raywenderlich.com [article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/128948/universal-links-make-connection) about working with Universal Links.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Yes, this is if we are using our own domain. I have already implemented this. What my question is that, if I tap a google link, then it should open my app. I hope it is clear.